# make an 'AND' condition with all elements in the list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to filter/select conditions based on elements of an input list. So, for example, I have something like:

```
filters = ['category', 'name']
# I am just trying to select the columns which would match as follows:

data = {'category_name_courses': ["Spark","PySpark","Python","pandas"], 'category_name_area': ["cloud", "cloud", "prog", "ds"], 'some_other_column': [0, 0, 0, 0]

x = pd.DataFrame(data)

selections = list()

for col in x.columns:
    if ('name' in col) and ('category' in col):
        selections.append(col)
```

In my case, this `if` condition or some other way of selection should be built by 'ANDing' everything from this input list

Comment: What is the "something" you want to do? Can you provide a sample DataFrame?

Comment: @XxJames07- how is the header a non-hashable object? Here they are strings

Comment: sorry, i didn't realize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit shows that you want to filter columns based on their **name**.

Simply use:

```
filters = ['category', 'name']
for col in x.columns:
    if all(x in col for x in filters):
        print(col)
```

Output:

```
category_name_courses
category_name_area
```

##### older answer: filtering **values**

You can do almost what you suggested:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([['flow', 'x', 'category'],['x','x','flow']])

for col in x.columns:
    if ('flow' in x[col].values) and ('category' in x[col].values):
        # Do something with this column...
        print(f'column "{col}" matches')
```

Using a list of matches:

```
filters = ['category', 'flow']

for col in x.columns:
    if all(x in x[col].values for x in filters):
        # Do something with this column...
        print(f'column "{col}" matches')
```

Or, more efficiently, using a `set`:

```
filters = set(['category', 'flow'])
for col in x.columns:
    if set(x[col]) >= filters:
        # Do something with this column...
        print(f'column "{col}" matches')
```

Example:

```
column "2" matches
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, do you want?

```
reg_str = '&'.join(filters)
x.filter(regex=reg_str)
```

Output:

```
  category_name_courses category_name_area
0                 Spark              cloud
1               PySpark              cloud
2                Python               prog
3                pandas                 ds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it (if I understand your problem correctly):

You have a list of condition, and you want to sure, that the column includes all of it.

```
filters = ['category', 'name']
# x is some pandas dataframe
# I am trying to create something which would be equivalent of:

for col in x.columns:
    boo = True
    for condition in filters:
        if not condition in col:
            boo = False
            break
    if boo == True:
        #to do something
```

Answer (score 0):

I really did not understand the question. I assume you want to find all column names witch contains any value in the given list.

The pandas data frame has loads of methods and functionalities. You may be familiar with `dt` which allows one to apply `datetime` functionalities to a given column.

In the same way one can use `str` for `string` functionalities.

So you can see if any string is in any value (row) of a column:

```
a_df.str.contains("string")
```

it will return a list of `bool` where condition is met.

One can use `|` (`or`) to check multiple strings.

```
a_df.str.contains("string|someting")
```

So the line should look like:

```
x.columns.str.contains("|".join(filters))
```

Now you have the mask you can apply it:

```
x.columns[x.columns.str.contains("|".join(filters))]
```

Since you have the column names you can access the column data itself:

```
x[x.columns[x.columns.str.contains("|".join(filters))]]
```

output:

```
  category_name_courses category_name_area
0                 Spark              cloud
1               PySpark              cloud
2                Python               prog
3                pandas                 ds
```